# How to redefine system-wide shortcuts in AutoIt?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autoit

On `Windows`, when you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, the Windows Search utility will pop up. I want to redefine this short cut and point to another program (yes, it's also a search utility, [everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)). I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
; open everything.exe
HotKeySet("#f", "open_everything")

; # win
; ^ ctrl
; + shift
; ! alt

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

; open everything
Func open_everything()
    MsgBox(4, "", "everything ... ")
EndFunc
```

When I change the short cut to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, everything works.

```
; open everything.exe
HotKeySet("#z", "open_everything")

; # win
; ^ ctrl
; + shift
; ! alt

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

; open everything
Func open_everything()
    MsgBox(4, "", "everything ... ")
EndFunc
```

Any ideas of this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AutoIt help file. Page is Function Reference -> HotKeySet. The following hotkeys cannot be set: *Win+B,D,E,F,L,M,R,U; and Win+Shift+M*

*These are built-in Windows shortcuts. Note: Win+B and Win+L might only be reserved on Windows XP and above.*

Much easier is to for example bind the key on Ctrl+F and get used to pressing that.